How to get numbers
myPattern = @"?:[.]?[\d]+(?:[,.]*\d)*";

However, I would like to exclude the numbers following the dollar sign ($), and want to exclude numbers in parentheses (){}[].
For example:
input text (match)
-----------------------------
abc123,000.5xyz (match:123,000.5)
abc.5xyz (match:.5)
abc0.2xyz  (match:0.2)
abc123.2xyz (match:123.2)
abc$123xyz (false)
abc(123)77xyz (match:77)
abc12{123}xyz (match:12)
abc[123]xyz (false)


Also, try https://regex101.com/r/jCLNjs/1, (?:(?<!\$)\.\d+|(?<![\d$]\.?)(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d{4,})(?:\.\d+)?)(?![^()]*\))(?![^][]*])(?![^{}]*}). If you need to avoid matching inside paired nested brackets,  please let know.

Another idea: (?>(?<![$\d,.])\.?\d[\d,.]*)(?![^)(]*\)|[^}{]*}|[^\]\[]*]) (it's not the most efficient but performs well, not very accurate about the number)

You can use this regex:
(?<![${([\d]\.?)(?=[.\d])(?:\d+(?:,\d{3})*)?(?:\.\d+)?(?![]})])

It matches:

(?<![${([\d]\.?) : negative lookbehind for $, (, [, { or a digit (the latter prevents matching from the middle of a number) followed by an optional .
(?=[.\d]) : positive lookahead for a digit or .
(?:\d+(?:,\d{3})*)?(?:\.\d+)? : regex to match a number with optional thousands and decimal parts
(?![]})]) : negative lookahead for ], }, or )

Regex demo on regex101

This works as long as the representation of the numeric value is correct. For example, if the string were abc 1,0.5,0.7xyz it would match 1, 0.5 and 0.7.

@CarySwoveland yeah, but we could spend hours thinking of edge cases like that, none of which are in OPs question. If/when OP says that's a problem I'll revisit it. After all, for all we know OP might want it to match 1, 0.5 and 0.7

You could match what you want to avoid, and make use of a capture group to capture the values that you want.
For the current example data where there is no nesting of brackets:
(?:\([^()]*\)|\[[^][]*]|{[^{}]*}|\$\d[.,\d]*)|(\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?|\.\d+)


(?: Non capture group for the 4 alternatives

\([^()]*\) Match from (...)
| Or
\[[^][]*] Match from [...]
| Or
{[^{}]*} Match from {...}
| Or
\$\d[.,\d]* Match $ a digit and optional repetitions of . , or a digit


) Close the non capture group
| Or
( Capture group 1

\d+ Match 1+ digits
(?:,\d{3})* Match optional repetitions of , and 3 digits
(?:\.\d+)? Optionally match . and 1+ digits
| Or
\.\d+ Match a dot and 1+ digits


) Close group 1

See a regex demo

OMG! Is it conceivable Bird #4 has has made a mistake?! Twice I tried "abc 12,3.05", washing my hands and donning a mask between tries. Both times in matched "12" and "3.05". Horrors! There is a similar problem with my answer.

@CarySwoveland  I had a mask on when writing this. You could always repeat matching 1 or more digits instead of 3 like https://regex101.com/r/3RH2Hb/1

The following is a similar idea to @Thefourthbird's answer except I convert matches to empty strings. If the resulting string is empty there is no representation of a number to be extracted; else what remains is the number of interest.
I have written the regex in extended (a.ka. free-spacing) mode to make it self-documenting.
  ^               # match the beginning of the string
  [^$([{.\d[{(]*  # match >= 0 chars other than those in the char class
|                 # or
  \$.*            # match '$' then rest of the line
|                 # or
  \([^)]*\)       # match '(', >= 0 chars other than ')' then ')'
|                 # or
  \[[^\]]*\]      # match '[', >= 0 chars other than ']' then ']'
|                 # or
  \{[^}]*\}       # match '{', >= 0 chars other than '}' then '}'
|                 # or

  (?!             # begin negative lookahead (to protect a valid number) 
    (?:           # begin non-capture group
      \.?\d+      # match '.' 0 or 1 times then >= 1 digits
    |             # or
      0\.\d+      # match '0' then '.' 0 or 1 times then >= 1 digits
    |             # or
      [1-9]       # match a digit other than zero
      \d{0,2}     # match 0-2 digits
      (?:         # begin non-capture group
        ,\d{3}    # match ',' then 3 digits
      )*          # end non-capture group and execute if >= 0 times
      (?:         # begin non-capture group
        \.\d+     # match '.' then  >= 1 digits
      )?          # end non-capture group and execute if 0 or 1 times 
    )             # end non-capture group
    (?!           # begin negative lookahead
     [.,\d]       # match a char in the char class
    )             # end negative lookahead
  )               # end negative lookahead
  [\d,.]+         # match >= 1 chars in the char class

|                 # or
  [^\d.,]+$       # match >= 1 chars not in the char class
                  # at the end of the string

Demo
Note that most advanced features of this regex is a negative lookahead. It therefore should work with most regex flavours, including C#.
